# Solr indexes are not visible

Tags: solr

We're using a **training server** to create **solr indexes** and uploading them to another (solr) server via rsync.

Until now, everything has been fine. Now, our index size on one core has increased drastically and our solr instances are refusing to read those indexes on that core. Also, they are ignoring those indexes without any exceptions. (we sure are reloading the cores or restarting `tomcat` after `rsyncs`)

ie: in `solr stats`, `numDocs` is `0` or `/select?q=*:*` is not returning any results..

Just to answer the question, are those indexes corrupted, we have regenerated them a couple of times. But nothing has changed. When we try to use smaller indexes, they are being read fine.

our solrconfig.xml in this core is like this; https://gist.github.com/983ebb13c895c9cccbfb

Comment: can you share your catalina log file?

Comment: Hey evan, we have investigated the log files. Nothing was pointing to an error. But we have realized that our "segments" files were corrupted. That was most probably something to do with our trainers.

Comment: have you tried using built in replication?

Comment: Why dont you try view the index file ?

Comment: if your `segments` is  corrupted you may try to recover it. Read here:http://solr.pl/en/2011/01/17/checkindex-for-the-rescue/

Answer (score 2):

Copying your index using rsync is a *bad idea*.  Your Solr server may not have completed writing files to disc when you initiate the copy operation, and you could end up with corruption.  The only safe way to do this is to shut down the master (source index), shut down the slave (destination index), remove the entire content of the slave's index directory, copy the master's index across, and then restart everything.

A better approach is what was suggested by Peer Allan above - use Solr's built-in replication support.  See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication.

Comment: I agree, we solved a lot of issues by switching from a file-copy solution to using the replication that's already built in.